# N1ql -> IN operator does not work with other conditions

Tags: node.js, couchbase, sql++

The following query works just fine when only IN operator is used
`SELECT META().id FROM bucket_name WHERE description IN ['Item1','Item2']`

But when I fire this query it gives me a blank result
`SELECT META().id FROM bucket_name WHERE id = 123 AND description IN ['Item1','Item2']`

Am I doing something wrong or somebody else has faced the same problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have to take your "IN" condition into parenthesis to make it work:

```
SELECT META().id FROM bucket_name WHERE id = 123 AND (description IN ['Item1','Item2'])
```

It has to do with the [precedence level of the operators evaluation by N1QL](http://docs.couchbase.com/prebuilt/n1ql/n1ql-dp3/operators.html) processor

If you run it with [EXPLAIN](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-query-language-0.1/#explain) keyword it will show how it links conditions against each other.

e.g.

```
explain SELECT META().id FROM bucket_name WHERE id = 123 AND (description IN ['Item1','Item2'])
```

vs

```
explain SELECT META().id FROM bucket_name WHERE id = 123 AND description IN ['Item1','Item2']
```

Answer (score 4):

With the latest N1QL developer preview (http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/n1ql-dp3/n1ql-intro.html) the IN clause does not need to be parenthesized, so this should work:

```
SELECT META(b).id FROM bucket_name b WHERE id = 123 AND description IN ['Item1','Item2']
```

You need to pass the bucket name (or alias) to META() I think because N1QL now supports queries on multiple buckets.